# Width and Height of the Image in RenderTargetBitmap in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawingvisual

Using the below code I'm drawing on `DrawingVisual` then rendering it to an `Image` using `RenderTargetBitmap`. The final `Image` is later added to a `Canvas` and displayed on the screen.

My problem is with the `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` arguments the `RenderTargetBitmap` method wants. What valued should I give to it? I have noticed that if I give it lower numbers parts of the image is not rendered. On what basis should I choose these? I have given it 1000 in the code below.

```
public class ModelBeamSectionNamesInPlan : Image
{
    private readonly VisualCollection _visuals;
    public ModelBeamSectionNamesInPlan(BaseWorkspace space)
    {
        var typeface = Settings.BeamTextTypeface;
        var cultureinfo = Settings.CultureInfo;
        var flowdirection = Settings.FlowDirection;
        var beamtextsize = Settings.BeamTextSize;
        var beamtextcolor = Settings.InPlanBeamTextColor;

        beamtextcolor.Freeze();
        const double scale = 0.6;

        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            foreach (var beam in Building.ModelBeamsInTheElevation)
            {
                var text = beam.Section.Id;
                var ft = new FormattedText(text, cultureinfo, flowdirection,
                                           typeface, beamtextsize, beamtextcolor,
                                           null, TextFormattingMode.Display)
                {
                    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                };

                // Draw Text
                dc.DrawText(ft, space.FlipYAxis(x, y));
            }
        }

        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(1000, 1000, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
        Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the [ContentBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.contentbounds.aspx) property of the DrawingVisual?

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, `drawingVisual.ContentBounds.Width` gives me `-Infinity`.

Comment: Did you perhaps try [DescendantBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.descendantbounds.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the DrawingVisual's `ContentBounds` property, which

> gets the bounding box for the contents of the ContainerVisual

or the `DescendantBounds` property which

> gets the union of all the content bounding boxes for all of the
>   descendants of the ContainerVisual, but not including the contents of
>   the ContainerVisual.

Something like this should work:

```
var bounds = drawingVisual.DescendantBounds;
var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)Math.Ceiling(bounds.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(bounds.Height),
    96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, this was very helpful. Is this the only way to get the Bitmap? Is there any other way in WPF better or more efficient than this one?

Comment: You mean another way to create a bitmap from a Visual? That's exactly the purpose of RenderTargetBitmap. If you just wanted to draw a copy of a Visual, you might as well use a VisualBrush, e.g. as Fill of a Rectangle.

Comment: Yes I meant is there another way? Like you know there are a bunch of ways to do things in WPF. Regarding the VisualBrush things, something just occurred to me, can we store each English letter as different VisualBrush and create a more efficient text system like SHX fonts in autocad? I wanted to ask this as a separate question, but I'm afraid it is a bit general.

Comment: More efficient? I guess not, as text rendering is already quite efficient in WPF. This article may be interesting: [Typography in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742190.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Great article.